# Perform an action only when resizing from a screen width greater than 1000px to something below 1000px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my footer to change depending on the screen width, so when its below 1000px I have all my social media links as text in a block format, but when above 1000px I replace social media links with the logos and become inline. The way I have it now works well except for the fact that when it resizes from ex) 700px to 500px it adds another link so ill have multiple "twitter" links being added such as (twitter twitter twitter). I only want it to be added when the previous screen size was greater than 1000 and drops below it. at the moment I'm using 'append.to' so I can add a span tag when the change in screen size occurs

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nav-mobile ul').hide();
    $('#socialbtns').removeClass("socialbtns");
    $('#ig').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-instagram");
    $('#twitter').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-twitter");
    $('#linkin').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-linkedin");
    $('#trademark').removeClass("footer3");
    $('#nav-mobile').click(function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('#nav-mobile ul > li >a')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#nav-mobile ul').slideToggle();
        }
    });
    resize();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        resize();
        if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 999px)").matches) {
            $(' <span> Instagram </span>').appendTo("#ig");
            $(' <span> Twitter </span>').appendTo("#twitter");
            $('<span> LinkedIn </span>').appendTo("#linkin");
            $('#trademark').addClass("footer3");
        }
    });
});


function resize() {

    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1000px)").matches) {
        $('#nav-mobile').hide();
        $('#socialbtns').addClass("socialbtns");
        $('#ig').addClass("fa fa-md fa-instagram");
        $('#twitter').addClass("fa fa-md fa-twitter");
        $('#linkin').addClass("fa fa-md fa-linkedin");
        $('span').remove();
        $('#trademark').removeClass("footer3");
    } else {
        $('#nav-mobile').show();
        $('#socialbtns').removeClass("socialbtns");
        $('#ig').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-instagram");
        $('#twitter').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-twitter");
        $('#linkin').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-linkedin");
        $('#trademark').addClass("footer3");
    }

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/main.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Menu Icon -->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav id="nav-mobile">
            <a>Menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="bio.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="photos.html">Photography</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- Home Page -->
        <div class="img-container border">
            <header class="main-header">
                <div class="title">
                    <div class="name"> Luis Rodriguez </div>
                    <div class="services"> Web Developer & Photographer </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Content Section -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section1">
            <img src="images/pg1.jpg" alt="Photography">
            <div class="titles"> Photography </div>
            <p> In this era a photo does much more than merely remind us of a moment. It has by far become one of the most diverse forms of influence. We capture pictures of loved ones and bring tears of joy years later, while on the other hand busiensses
                rely on a picture to convey a "million words" to potential clients. Regardless of your story, the right photo should amaze you every time you see it.
            </p>
            <div class="title-button">
                <a href="photos.html"> My Photos </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section2">
            <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="Code">
            <div class="titles"> WebDev </div>
            <p> When you ask someone to browse something online you really never know what they'll use anymore. You can have one person pull out their phone, another use a tablet, you've got someone on a desktop, and there may even be someone using their
                TV. Having a dynamic website is vital to ensuring that who ever is visiting your site can have a clean simple view to your page regardless of where they see it.
            </p>
            <div class="title-button">
                <a href="code.html">My Code</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <footer class="main-footer">
        <div class="footer1">
            <a href="bio.html">About</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer2">
            <div class="socialbtns" id="socialbtns">
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.twitter.com/baesicmedia" id="twitter" class="fa fa-md fa-twitter"><span id="twitter-text">Twitter</span></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="#" id="linkin" class="fa fa-md fa-linkedin"><span> LinkedIn</span></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/baesicfrs/" id="ig" class="fa fa-md fa-instagram"><span> Instagram</span></a>
            </div>
            <div id="trademark" class="footer3">
                &copy;2017 Baesic Media
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the easier way to do this is with css media queries. just hide/show the elements depending on the size.

Comment: You're right, I was overthinking this! Thanks!